# Running a for loop across a list of columns in a df

Tags: python, for-loop

I am able to effectively run a Logistic Regression with one variable, which gives me the output I desire

```
x=df['a']
y=df['outcome']

model = sm.GLM(y, x, family=sm.families.Binomial())
results = model.fit()
results.summary()
```

However, when I have multiple columns I want to do simple logistic regressions on (I want them to be simple, not multivariable), I receive an error when I try to pass it through a for loop.

```
x=df[['a', 'b', 'c']]
y=df['outcome']

for i in x:
    model = sm.GLM(y, i, family=sm.families.Binomial())
    results = model.fit()
    results.summary()
```

I receive the following error: ValueError: unrecognized data structures: <class 'numpy.ndarray'> / <class 'str'>

How can I loop through this to produce 3 unique simple Linear Regressions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for i in x: iterates over column names not the data

do this

```
x=df[['a', 'b', 'c']]
y=df['outcome']

for i in x:
    model = sm.GLM(y, df[i], family=sm.families.Binomial())
    results = model.fit()
    results.summary()
```

if you need to save results you can append them to a data structure e.g. create `model_results = []` and then append to it